# Tmux: <Crtl>-b doesn't work

Tags: linux, tmux

Every time I start tmux and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, the terminal prints `^B`. I am using Windows to connect to Raspberry Pi. I have tried Putty and Bitvise.

EDIT: finally I found a imperfect solution.

```
# Set the prefix to ^A.
unbind C-b
set -g prefix ^A
bind a send-prefix

# other ^A
unbind ^A
bind ^A last-window
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the shell started in `tmux` is not bash.  If it were, by default `bash` provides a binding for <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.  Other shells differ.

If you are really using bash, you can use `bind -p` to print the existing bindings.

The question, by the way, is vague regarding whether the problem exists on the local Windows machine, or on the remote Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I switched to Min, 'sshed' Raspberry Pi, and got the same result. I found a suspect line `"\C-b": self-insert` of the bindings. On my Mint, it is `"\C-b": backward-char`.

Comment: Then ultimately that's your answer: the unexpected difference in configuration.

Comment: This time, I used `bind '"\C-b": backward-char'`, then nothing happened when pressing <Ctrl>-b.

Comment: The shell that `tmux` runs should not be an issue. It isn't even an issue if tmux runs things that is _not_ a shell.

Answer (score -1):

Try also these settings in `.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind-key C-b 
set -g prefix 'C-a'
bind-key 'C-a' send-prefix
```

This works for me.